# jvm caching of method calls?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am doing some performance tests of a HTML stripper (written in java), that is to say, I pass a string (actually html content) to a method of the HTML stripper 
and the latter returns plain text (without HTML tags and meta information).

Here is an example of the concrete implementation

```
public void performanceTest() throws IOException {
    long totalTime;
    File file = new File("/directory/to/ten/different/htmlFiles");
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i) {
        for (File fileEntry : file.listFiles()) {

            HtmlStripper stripper = new HtmlStripper();
            URL url = fileEntry.toURI().toURL();
            InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
            String html = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, "UTF-8");
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            String text = stripper.getText(html);
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            totalTime = totalTime + (end - start);

      //The duration for the stripping of each file is computed here
     // (200 times for each time). That duration value decreases and then becomes constant
     //IMHO if the duration for the same file should always remain the same.
     //Or is a cache technique used by the JVM?         


        System.out.println("time needed for stripping current file: "+ (end -start));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Average time for one document: "
            + (totalTime / 2000));

}
```

But the duration for the stripping of each file is computed 200 times for each time and has a different decreasing value. IMHO if the duration for one and the same file X should always remain the same!? Or is a cache technique used by the JVM?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Horace

N.B:
- I am doing the tests local (NO remote, NO http) on my machine.
- I am using java 6 on Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is totally normal.  The JIT compiles methods to native code and optimizes them more heavily as they're more and more heavily used.  (The "constant" your benchmark eventually converges to is the peak of the JIT's optimization capabilities.)

You *cannot* get good benchmarks in Java without running the method many times *before* you start timing at all.

Comment: Might add here that microbenchmarking frameworks like [Google Caliper](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/) exist to help do that kind of initialization for you, but you still have to be smart about writing the benchmark itself.  Caliper itself is still a little raw, but I have found it quite useful.  I am sure other benchmark frameworks exist too.

Comment: FYI, Caliper is being worked up for a srs bsns release in the not-too-distant future.

Comment: Thank you very much guys. That explains the whole :-)

Comment: Thx Louis. The same answer from you saved my day some months ago :-)

Answer (score 0):

> IMHO if the duration for one and the same file X should always remain the same

Not in the presence of an optimizing just-in-time compiler. Among other things it keeps track of how many times a particular method/branch is used, and selectively compiles Java byte codes into native code.